# Async import loading issue with preact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, import, es6-modules

So, i am working on a project and have a constants folder which has subfolders

[image: THE FOLDER STRUCTURE LOOKS LIKE THIS]

The index.ts file has export statements for other files in their respective folders and internally have their index.ts files as

[image: export statements]

This is the index.ts inside the page folder

[image: index.ts inside page folder]

This is the VIDEO_GENERATION_CONSTANTS that i am exporting from this file

[image]

and importing it into files like this. I am seeing error while following the first strategy. I haven't encountered this error and i guess this is because of how modules are loaded asynchronously . Is my deduction correct ? If anyone can shed some more light on this , it could be really helpful

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this using Preact-CLI? Can't really help without a minimal reproduction, which Stack isn't really great for. If it is Preact-CLI, feel free to post on the tracker and I can take a look.

Comment: Yes this is preact-cli , what do you mean by tracker?

Comment: https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/issues

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with the code , the way modules were loading , causing the component to load first and the constants to load after , causing that issue . Apologies for taking your time . I will close this.